# Does Worldbuilding control what is on our "site tour"? (+ possible improvements)

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if each SE has any control over any part of the "site tour" under the `help` menu?

Primarily because I think it would be neat if there was a last little section talking about our specific community, we could mention things like stopping by `chat` and visiting our `question sandbox` or checking out the latest `challenge` or `blog`.

Obviously if it is shared for all sites, we can't do that.

<sub>Side-question that made me think of this: "What is the easiest way to get to chat?" (*answer seems to be scrolling to the bottom of the page and it's hidden in the orange links*)</sub>

Comment: By the way, clicking on the SE logo at the top left opens a menu which contains a link to chat. Probably quicker than scrolling.

Comment: Ah ha! I thought there might be a better way, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The parts of the tour that moderators can edit are: the first paragraph, the "ask about" list, and the "don't ask about" list.  We can also change the example question, within some pretty tight constraints.  Everything else is standard across Stack Exchange and can't be edited.

Comment: That's a shame, I think it would ruin the flow and purpose of the tour if that stuff were in the first paragraph.

Comment: I agree; that stuff doesn't belong in the first paragraph.  You might want to ask a question on Meta.SE asking for more customization options.  Such a question will fare better if you can point out ways it would help other sites too.  (For example, some sites have weekly chat events that could be mentioned, others have sandboxes, etc.)